# Rethink db order by optional field

Tags: rethinkdb

Docs:

```
[{
  id: 111,
  weight: 1 
},{
  id: 222,
},{
  id: 333,
  weight: -1
}]
```

I want to order the docs by `weight` if `weight` not exists treat its `weight` as `0`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function as mentioned [here](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/order_by/) with [default](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#default):

```
r.table(TABLE_NAME).orderBy(r.asc(function(doc) {
    return doc("weight").default(0)
}));
```